# ASP.NET MVC access configuration in static methods

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm using asp.net core and loading application configuration into controllers using the standard DI mechanism fine, but I now need to access the configuration in a static method on a static class (its a bunch of helper methods that, in this case, require a few of the config settings)

So far I've been passing the relevant settings entries in as parameters but I wondered if there's a better way of simply getting the entire config object directly from wherever the DI services collection stores it.

Comment: Expose a static property and set it when configuring your startup. from there you other methods will have access to it

Comment: @Nkosi yeah, fair enough but it just sounds a bit hacky, using a global to bypass the DI :-)

Comment: well given that you can't inject into a static class it is your only option. Unless you change from a static Util class and have the config injected like all the other places you have DI

Comment: @Nkosi I was expecting a way to get at the DI container and "manually" extract the object.

Comment: It still means setting a static member on the static class, which does not play nice with conventional DI.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question seemed very interesting to me because I've been dealing with something similar recently and I have three different approaches (comments, pros and cons are very welcome):

1.a. - first one is hacky too... What if you add an extension method in that (let's call it UtilsProvider)  and then you get the configuration calling that estension method in the

```
 public static class UtilsProvider
    {
        private static string _configItemOne;

        public static IServiceProvider SetUtilsProviderConfiguration(this IServiceProvider serviceProvider, IConfigurationRoot configuration)
        {
            // just as an example:
            _configItemOne= configuration.GetValue<string>("CONFIGITEMONE");
            return serviceProvider;
        }
        // AND ALL YOUR UTILS THAT WOULD USE THAT CONFIG COULD USE IT
    }
```

And, that extension method would be called from your Startup class Configure method:

```
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
            {
                #region AddUtilsConfig

                serviceProvider.SetUtilsProviderConfiguration(Configuration);

                #endregion

...
```

1.b. - Instead of passing the entire IConfigurationRoot instance we could pass many things like the concrete parameter or a client to a Service that holds environment configuration values and call that service from your static class first time you need that configu property.

2.- Another approach that should also work is described here (link below)  but consist in something similar and it is to pass HostingEnvironment to a estatic class in the same Configure method in the startup class  (http://www.blakepell.com/asp-net-core-dependency-injection-and-custom-classes )

```
public static class UtilsProvider
    {

        public static IHostingEnvironment HostingEnvironment { get; set; }        

...
    }
```

And in startup...

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            ...

            // Have to be careful with static properties, they persist throughout the life time
            // of the application.  
            UtilsProvider.HostingEnvironment = env;
        }
```

Comment: Aye, I think most of the DI containers fail to be accessed from the rest of the code in a way you control, - they're all about "controlling your code". What we have left with is basically turning the config into globals (in the form of static classes) which always amuses me as this is the way we used ot handle global config decades ago. What is old is new, I just wait for a framework to appear that does this in a more fancy manner :-)